# How to repeat while loop for turn base combat java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
public class Game1 {
    public Game1 gamet1;
    public int card1Hp = 100;
    public int card2Hp = 80;
    public int card1Apc = 20;
    public int card2Apc = 30;


    //Constructor

    public void start() {
        while (card1Hp > 0 ) {
            battle();
        } 
    }

    public void battle() {
        System.out.println(card1Hp - card2Apc); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game1 gamet1 = new Game1();
        gamet1.start();
    } 

}
```

So I want to do a while loop in java where battle method gets launched while hp>0 but it keeps repeating and the hp only goes to 70 and won't keep going down to 0. How can I stop this infinte while loop. It just keeps printing 70 on and on and won't stop.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the same person, but there is an exact same code sample posted here: https://www.java-forums.org/new-java/97389-how-write-method-within-method.html and if they are not the same person, they probably have the same professor....

Comment: Sorry, that's me. I'll try not to clutter the internet with repeating questions... The answer for that question though is on getting the game to keep state for turn base combat and a much better design then what I'm trying to do initially. This one though answers the question of stopping the loop and solves the technical error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try decreasing the card1Hp. The println only calculates a difference and prints it out . It doesn't decrease the card1Hp. So:

```
 card1Hp = card1Hp - card2Apc;
 System.out.printLn(card1Hp);
```